# How do I forward authorization with the user JWT token in the header and compare it to the JWT token in the cookie to Auth user?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, jwt, mern

I have a problem with the logged in user, when I refresh the page the user gets lost. This is how I assign a JWT token:

```
const signToken = id => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, 'my-ultra-secure-and-ultra-long-secret', {
    expiresIn: '14d',
  });
};
```

This is how I send a token to a cookie with this function as well:

```
const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id);

  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 14 * 1000 * 60 * 24),
    httpOnly: true,
  };

  res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);

  // Remove password from output
  user.password = undefined;

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user,
    },
  });
};
```

This is my login controller:

```
exports.login = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // 1) Check if email and password exist
  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('Please provide email and password!', 400));
  }
  // 2) Check if user exists && password is correct
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

  if (user && (await user.correctPassword(password, user.password))) {
    createSendToken(user, 200, res);
  } else {
    return next(new AppError('Incorrect email or password', 401));
  }
});
```

This is my Protect controller (protect middleware):

exports.protect = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {

```
  // 1) Getting token and check of it's there
  let token;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
  ) {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  }
  if (!token) {
    return next(
      new AppError('You are not logged in! Please log in to get access.', 401)
    );
  }
  // 2) Verification token
  const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(
    token,
    'my-ultra-secure-and-ultra-long-secret'
  );
  // 3) Check if user still exists
  const currentUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);
  if (!currentUser) {
    return next(
      new AppError(
        'The user belonging to this token does no longer exist.',
        401
      )
    );
  }
  // 4) Check if user changed password after the token was issued
  if (currentUser.changedPasswordAfter(decoded.iat)) {
    return next(
      new AppError('User recently changed password! Please log in again.', 401)
    );
  }
  // GRANT ACCESS TO PROTECTED ROUTE
  req.user = currentUser;
  res.locals.user = currentUser;
  next();
});
```

This is my private route with this middleware:

```
router.route('/:id').get(authController.isLoggedIn, postController.getPost);
```

The problem is when I log in I get a cookie, but I can't access the protected route (I get an error token is undefind). When I refresh the page the user is lost but the cookie remains in storage. When I try to access the protect route via postman and when I add the Authorization Bearer to the header ..... (token) I can access it.

This is my frontend user reducer:

```
export const userLoginReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, isAuthenticated: false };
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, isAuthenticated: false, error: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return { loading: false, isAuthenticated: false, user: null };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is my user action:

```
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
    });

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      '/api/v1/users/login',
      { email, password },
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

   
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

This is my login screen:

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/';

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin);
  const { loading, error, isAuthenticated } = userLogin;
  console.log(isAuthenticated);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      history.push(redirect);
    }

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, history, redirect, error]);

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login(email, password));
  };
```

I stuck here about 2 days trying to complete this. Please someone help me :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting the jwt token in a cookie, you can read it from there when making a request. You can send the cookie automatically with axios by adding `withCredentials: true` in your axios config object, like:

```js
axios({
 withCredentials: true
})
```

On the server side, you can get the jwt cookie value by looking it on the `req.cookies` object, like:

```js
let token;
if (req.cookies.jwt) {
  token = req.cookies.jwt;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this works but it works
"let token;
if (req.cookies.jwt) {
  token = req.cookies.jwt;
}"

Now when i have cookie i can access protected route and when i delete cookie from storage or logout i cant. Thats nice. Now i wondering how can i keep user logged in. I display user name in a header when log in and thats okay but when i refresh page my user is gone and get error user.name is undefind

Comment: To understand how cookies work you can check https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html. For the refresh page issue, I would think in having another route to check the user session, like having a controller to verify the jwt token and return the user information as the name, while in the frontend you could have a loading state while you wait for the user session check. In case you are using react router, this can help you https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: The same user is lost when I log in and refresh the page (right one output) on that link you sent me